# Replace string by matching with the regular expressions in Java

Tags: java, regex

here monitorUrl contains- `http://host:8810/solr/admin/stats.jsp`
and monitorUrl sometimes can be-- `http://host:8810/solr/admin/monitor.jsp`

So i want to replace stats.jsp and monitor.jsp to ping

```
if(monitorUrl.contains("stats.jsp") || monitorUrl.contains("monitor.jsp")) {
                trimUrl = monitorUrl.replace("[stats|monitor].jsp", "ping");
            }
```

Anything wrong with the above code. As I get the same value of monitorUrl in trimUrl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) instead of replace (and escape the dot as Alan pointed out):

```
trimUrl = monitorUrl.replaceAll("(stats|monitor)\\.jsp", "ping");
```

From the documentation:

> **`replaceAll`**
>
> ```
> public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)
> ```
>
> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

---

Note: You may also want to consider matching only after a `/` and checking that it is at the end of the line by using `$` at the end of your regular expression.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanations. How can we match starting from the last `/` and till the end of string. As I very much new with the regex.

Comment: `"/(stats|monitor).jsp$"` or `"(?<=/)(stats|monitor).jsp$"`

Comment: @Raihan Jamal: What do you mean by "will not work"? You can just replace it with "/ping" isntead of "ping". Won't that work for you?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
trimUrl = monitorUrl.replaceAll("(?:stats|monitor)\\.jsp", "ping");
```

Explanation:

1. `replaceAll()` treats the first argument as a regex, while `replace()` treats it as a literal string.
2. You use parentheses, not square brackets, to group things.  `(?:...)` is the *non-capturing* form of group; you should use the capturing form - `(...)` - only when you really need to capture something.
3. `.` is a metacharacter, so you need to escape it if you want to match a literal dot.

And finally, you don't have to check for the presence of the sentinel string separately; if it's not there, `replaceAll()` just returns the original string.  For that matter, so does `replace()`; you could also have done this:

```
trimUrl = monitorUrl.replace("stats.jsp", "ping")
                    .replace("monitor.jsp", "ping");
```

Comment: +1 for the escape dot, but the last line has the same problem as Zernike's answer: `"monitor.jsstats.jsp"` will become `"pinging"`.

Comment: True, but according to the question, the final segment can only be `monitor.jsp` or `stats.jsp`.  That's how I read it, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No needs to use regex (also `replace()` don't use regex).

```
trimUrl = monitorUrl.replace("stats.jsp", "ping").replace("monitor.jsp", "ping");
```

Comment: If you do that `"monitor.jsstats.jsp"` will become `"pinging"`.